# Does it make a sens to use JMS without Message orineted middleware?

Tags: java, jms

I'm new to `JMS` and now trying to integrate it with my applications. I've decided to use [apachemq](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-core/5.7.0) jars at the client side.

So, if I avoid the communication through the message broker `ApacheMQ` and  communicate between the parts of the application directly, will it make a sense? Is the main benefit of the `JMS API` lost in that case?

Couldn't someone explain it in a nutshell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMS is a API specification that describes how applications can send and receive messages through messaging middle-ware in a standard way and is portable across multiple JMS providers. Without a middle-ware (or broker), just the JMS APIs is of no use. So you need both, broker and JMS API implementation provided by that broker.

Comment: Doesn't it introduce a kind of coupling to a particular message broker? For, instance we decided to migrate from ApacheMQ to HornetQ. Will it be painful?

Comment: Well! the main intention of JMS was to make migration from one provider to another provider simple and painless. Many vendors implement features that specific to their broker. My assumption is that migration should be less painful if vendor specific features are not used in application.